Weird C array declaration
So I found out a weird problem with C array declaration. I tried two different way of the declaring an array in C (not really different). Both seem to work the same but my teacher say the one I use is wrong.
At class my teacher teach me to declare an array like this
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

int main() {
    int arr[SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 };
    return 0;
}

But when i do the exercise i do this
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int size = 0;
    printf("Input size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    int arr[size];
    
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

The error show up in the problem tab:

"expression must have a constant value"

But I still run it and the result still show up correctly.
Can anyone explain why this happen?

Variable length arrays are supported in C (from a certain version), but not in standard C++. Which IDE/compiler are you using ? Also please post the exact error message you get. If it's indeed a compilation error, the program cannot run.

Also note that while variable length arrays are an official part of C, variable length arrays  with automatic storage duration as in your post are officially optional, i.e. it is a feature that standard C compilers are not required to provide.

Check the return value from scanf! Initializing size is smart, but if scanf failed you're trying to declare an array of zero elements, which is other sorts of trouble. If scanf succeeds, validate that input. What do you think your computer thinks of you declaring an automatic storage duration array of 4,000,000,000 integers?

size should probably also be of type size_t and you should scan with the corresponding correct format specifier.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

"The error show up in the problem tab" hmmm.... since you get a program you can run, it can't be an error. It must be a warning.

@4386427 or it is an error and the binary from the last successful build is executed instead.

What compiler and build command do you use? Do you use a C standard version that is at least C99? In C99 VLA were introduced and in C11 they were made optional. If you delete the executable, can you still compile and run your code with that error/warning message?

@Gerhardh VLA are mandatory in the current version of C (C23). A compiler may still declare __STDC_NO_VLA__ but now meaning that it does not support object definitions of VLA type. But it must still support the syntax when an array is part of a function parameter list.

@Lundin thanks for clarification. That is what I meant with "optional".

@Gerhardh They were entirely optional in C11 and C17 but not any longer.

Neither is "wrong" as such. The former is a "classic" static size array, the latter is a variable-length array (VLA). Neither can be resized once declared and both will most likely get allocated on the stack.
There are some concerns regarding using VLA, because when using them like you do here, we really must sanitize the program input first to check if the size entered is reasonable, or otherwise we risk stack overflow. But they aren't "wrong".
You seem to be using a severely outdated compiler if you get warnings, because VLA has been in the C language since the year 1999.
If your teacher didn't already know all of this or is forcing you to use a compiler from the 1980s (Borland Turbo?), they are severely incompetent and should not be teaching programming.

The other possibility is they're using a reasonably modern C++ compiler that does not provide an extension to support VLAs. This is also a bad practice.
